# How to define new cell manually in Jupyter Dashboard?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I use Jupyter Notebook with the Dashboards extensions to create an interactive UI which layout can be edited in the Dashboard view.

My code creates several plots and outputs which are called from the same notebook code cell. As a result in Dashboard view they appear in the same cell. I want to define manually to which cell each output is placed and then be able to arrange and resize with drag and drop in Dashboard view.

```
username_widget = widgets.Text(description='Username:')
password_widget = widgets.Password(description='Password:')
login_button = widgets.Button(description='Login', button_style='success')

def login_and_load(b):
        data = rm.get_data()
        load_plots(data)

def load_plots(data):
    plot1 = rm.load_ratings_plot1(data)
    plot2 = rm.load_ratings_plot2(data)
    py.offline.iplot(plot1, filename='plot1') #Force plot1 in Cell 1
    py.offline.iplot(plot2, filename='plot2') #Force plot2 in Cell 2

login_button.on_click(login_and_load) 

login_menu = [username_widget, password_widget, login_button]
widgets.HBox(login_menu) #Force login_menu in Cell 3
```

Current Dashboard output:

```
Cell 1: login_menu, plot1, plot2
```

Desired Dashboard output:

```
Cell1: login_menu
Cell2: plot1
Cell3: plot2
```